# Add a QPushButton into a QTableWidgetItem in a QTableWidget, How to make it Qt::AlignHCenter

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

```
for(int i=0; i<page.size(); i++){
    User user= Poco::AnyCast<User>(*it);
    ui.table->setItem(i,0,new QTableWidgetItem(user.userName)); 
    ui.table->setItem(i,1,new QTableWidgetItem(user.sex));
    ui.table->setItem(i,2,new QTableWidgetItem(user.age));

    QPushButton* btn_edit = new QPushButton();
    btn_edit = new QPushButton();
    btn_edit->setText("Edit");
    ui.table->setCellWidget(i,3,(QWidget*)btn_edit);

    ++it;
}
```

I add a QPushButton into the cell with the function setCellWidget(),
I know, if it's a QTableWidgetItem, I can use :

```
ui.table->item(0,3)->setTextAlignment(QT::AlignHCenter)
```

But it is a Widget,

```
QTableWidgetItem item = ui.table->item(0,3);
```

the item is null.

I can get the cell by use

```
ui.table->cellWidget(0,3).
```

How should I do to make the button centered in the cell?

Comment: You have memory leak here: `QPushButton* btn_edit = new QPushButton(); btn_edit = new QPushButton();` (because this code allocated pair of buttons, but use only second of them)

Comment: @Ilya alright, that's a mistake…… thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget();
QPushButton* btn_edit = new QPushButton();
btn_edit->setText("Edit");
QHBoxLayout* pLayout = new QHBoxLayout(pWidget);
pLayout->addWidget(btn_edit);
pLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
pLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
pWidget->setLayout(pLayout);
ui.table->setCellWidget(i, 3, pWidget);
```