# How to make background of cell widget inside QTableWidget not selectable?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtablewidget, qpushbutton

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24909605/3125006 shows how to add a QPushButton into a QTableWidget cell. This works perfectly.

But then the background area around the PushButton is selectable. (Background turns into selection color when clicked). How can I prevent that?

[image]

Comment: `TableWidget->setstylesheet("QTableWidget::item{ selection-background-color: rgb(255,255,255)}"),`

Comment: or `"QTableWidget::item:selected{ background-color: rgb(255,255,255)}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in Pogrammer_ARM's comment is a suitable workaround. With corrected case:

```
QTableWidget* tblSensors = new QTableWidget();
tblSensors->setStyleSheet("QTableWidget::item{ selection-background-color: rgb(255,255,255)}");
```

Comment: Happy to help)))